# VBA - Does Worksheet.Select not longer have (replace) argument?

Tags: vba, excel, selection

I've tried using the following code to select all `Worksheets` in the `Workbook`:

```
Public Sub selectAllWS()
Dim ws As Worksheet
   For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
      ws.Select False
   Next
End Sub
```

However, this doesn't seem to work -- it doesn't select multiple `Worksheets`.

(Sidenote: I know I can use `Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Select`. I don't want to do this -- I'm experimenting if I can select `Sheets` across multiple `Workbooks`.

I'm running the latest version of Excel 2016.

Comment: Try passing True for the first sheet, then False for the rest.

Comment: Why are you using `False` if you want them selected?

Comment: What is your purpose for selecting multiple workbooks?

Answer (score 1):

This is a way you could accomplish this, and this does use the `Worksheets(Array`:

```
Workbooks("Book.xlsx").Activate
Workbooks("Book.xlsx").Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Select
Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Activate
Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Select
```

side note:
As asked in the comments I am unsure why you would do this, especially since using `.Select` is not the proper coding way in VBA.